# Linq2Sql: Does HasValue and != null, work the same for nullable types?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there any reason why I should choose one of these over the other? Or doesn't it really matter?

```
var a = data.Cars.Where(ø => ø.LicensePlate != null);

var b = data.Cars.Where(ø => ø.LicensePlate.HasValue);
```

I have used `!= null` before, but starting to think I should maybe switch, since HasValue kind of reads better. What do you guys think? Is there any difference at all? Other than one character extra? Any performance differences? Sql differences?

Comment: I like the use of the norwegian Ø as an identifier in code. :)

Comment: @KristoferA-Huagati.com Me too, as it prevents auto-complete for other stuff from coming up. `x` usually works for this too though, but I never use `ø` or anything starting with that letter for anything else :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, both statements are the same and you ought to choose whichever one you find more readable.

Something interesting to note is that the compiler will replace `null` comparisons on a `Nullable<T>` with a call to `HasValue`.  In other words this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int? i = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(i != null);
        Console.WriteLine(i.HasValue);
    }
}
```

gets compiled to this:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int? i = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(i.HasValue);
    Console.WriteLine(i.HasValue);
}
```

Comment: nice! how do you see the result of a compilation like that?

Comment: I used Reflector to analyze the assembly - http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/